# use datetime objects to filter queryset in Django (truncate to days)

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a question regarding filtering with datetime.
I have a following code:

```
def filter_by_transaction_date(self, queryset):
    if self.user_filter.from_date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__gte=self.user_filter.from_date)

    if self.user_filter.to_date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__lte=self.user_filter.to_date)
    return queryset
```

where queryset  is obviously a queryset,

```
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
self.user_filter.from_date== models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
self.user_filter.to_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

What in this case filtering does it that check whether or not created_at field contains between 2 datetimes, that is we basically operate timestamps here.

Issue. For example if object is created **26 august 13-45** and  `self.user_filter.to_date` is **26 august 03-00**, then this object would be filtered out.
What I want is to filter them based on days only. For example if object is created **26 august 13-45** and `self.user_filter.to_date` is **16 august 03-00** – both datetimes are still belong to one date , which is **26 august**. I want to use only days and somehow truncate hours, minutes, seconds, etc on both  `created_at` and (  `self.user_filter.from_date ,  self.user_filter.to_date`) and compare only year, month and day.

Target result ;

object is created **26 august 13-45** and  `self.user_filter.to_date` is **26 august 03-00**,
we truncate time, keep only date
we compare **26 august** <= **26 august** -`True`, object gets inside filter...

Sorry for entangled explanation, if so

Thanks...

Comment: You're using zone aware date objects?

Comment: @Ramy Mohamed . Yes, i use `make_aware`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date):

```
def filter_by_transaction_date(self, queryset):
    if self.user_filter.from_date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__date__gte=self.user_filter.from_date.date())

    if self.user_filter.to_date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__date__lte=self.user_filter.to_date)
    return queryset
```

Comment: I had tried this one already and it did filter out all enrties completelly.  I guess if left side of lookup is now  date only and right side is datetime, it cant be compared directly...

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich: to the best of my knowledge, it can, it will basically set the hours, minutes, and seconds to zero on the left side so to speak, and than make the comparison. The first `__gte` however will need to convert to a `.date()`, you are correct on that part.

Comment: Tnaks for the possible solution . I will have checked it tommorow at work.